# Can Spring autogenerate an 'Allow' header on an OPTIONS method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-options-method

When I configure my `RequestMapping`s in Spring MVC, I'd like to automatically generate the proper `Allow` header when the `OPTIONS` method is used.

For example, with this controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> getTest() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Right now if I do an `OPTIONS` request to that URL I get a 405, method not allowed. Instead I'd like it to automatically respond with

`Allow: GET, OPTIONS` and `204 - No content`

I've got one idea adding an interceptor like so:

```
@Override 
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            if("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
                response.setHeader("Allow", "GET, OPTIONS");
                response.setStatus(204);
                //TODO figure out the @Controller and what possible methods exist
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        //Deleted excess methods for brevity
    });
}
```

Does this functionality exist without me writing a custom interceptor? If not, how might I solve the `TODO` and lookup what annotations exist on the same URL the `OPTIONS` call had happened on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extend on Sotiros' and jhadesdev's answers. If using Java Config (like in Spring Boot) you can configure the `DispatchServlet` to enable `OPTIONS` request by configuring a `@Bean` like so:

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
    return servlet;
}
```

I then created a static helper that accepts HttpMethods varargs like so:

```
public static ResponseEntity<Void> allows(HttpMethod... methods) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    Set<HttpMethod> allow = new HashSet<>();
    for(HttpMethod method: methods){
        allow.add(method);
    }
    headers.setAllow(allow);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

This makes it simple to create my own `OPTIONS` mappings like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
ResponseEntity<Void> getProposalsOptions() {
    return allows(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
}
```

While I think it makes sense that Spring MVC could provide `OPTIONS` responses automatically, you can't do it via an `Interceptor`, but possibly via a custom `DispatcherServlet`.

The benefit of writing your own `OPTIONS` response is that it makes sense to customize the `OPTIONS` in some cases based on the user's roles. For example an unauthenticated user of the API may receive `Allow GET, OPTIONS` but an admin would get the full API `Allow GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` You would customize the response based on examining a user's roles when making the `OPTIONS` call.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a way to make it generic, this currently works although it's not generic.

set dispatchOptionsRequest to true for the dispatcher servlet in your web.xml, otherwise this prevents the servlet container to route the OPTIONS to the application:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Then adding this in the controller will return Allow: GET, OPTIONS and 204 - No content:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tryoptions", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public ResponseEntity tryOptions(HttpSession session) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Allow","OPTIONS, GET");
    return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Comment: After further experimentation, it appears that an interceptor isn't sufficient since by the time the interceptor is invoked Spring MVC already has detected that an OPTIONS `@RequestMapping` doesn't exist so the interceptor only passed through the `/error` URL

Answer (score 2):

[Changes introduced in Spring 4.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options) simplified that use case. From now the OPTIONS response is automatically prepared for all mappings in your application. There is no need to manually configure the framework as the feature is available out of the box.

> By default an HTTP OPTIONS request is handled by setting the "Allow"
>   response header to the HTTP methods explicitly declared on all
>   @RequestMapping methods with matching URL patterns. When no HTTP
>   methods are explicitly declared the "Allow" header is set to
>   "GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS"

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking this up today, it is done this way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public class UserRestController {
```

Simply defining `RequestMethod.OPTIONS` in your request mapping, defines the OPTIONS for the entire controller.

Here is the reference for more info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options